# Does the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\exp\{{-(m!)!}\}(D^m\phi)(0)$ converge for every $\phi \in C^\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Does the series $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\exp\{{-(m!)!}\}(D^m\phi)(0)$$
>   converge for every $\phi \in C^\infty$?

For analytic function $\phi$, we can show that the series converges by using Caushy-Schwartz inequality. But I believe in general that there is an example that the series diverges.

Although we have a Taylor expansion
$$\phi(x)-\phi(0)=x\phi'(x)+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}\phi^{(n)}(x)+\int_0^x\frac{y^n}{n!}\phi^{(n)}(y)dy$$
it seems to be useless because we don't have any information of $\phi^{(n)}(y)$.

How to make the growth of $\phi^{(n)}(0)$ fast?

Comment: The index of the sum should be $m$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks. I modified it.

Comment: How do you prove it for this analytic function $e^{2z}$?

Comment: Have you made use of the answer?

Comment: Perhaps a nonconstructive argument will work.  If the sum is always finite then $\ell(\phi) := \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\exp\{{-(m!)!}\}(D^m\phi)(0)$ is an everywhere defined linear functional on the Fréchet space $C^\infty([-1,1])$.  Use some sort of closed graph or automatic continuity principle to conclude that $\ell$ must be continuous.  Then show explicitly that $\ell$ is not continuous.  I will think about this some more.

Answer (score 1):

One way to assure the convergence of your series is to assume that the sequence $b_m =(D^m\phi)(0) $ to be bounded sequence since you have no problem with the convergence of the series $ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\exp\{{-(m!)!}\} $. This is due to the fact:

> If $|b_n| \leq M$ and $\sum_{n} a_n < \infty$ then $\sum_{n}a_nb_n$ converges.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - it is clear that the series converges for *some* $\phi$, but the question is whether it must converge for *all* $\phi \in C^\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose $\psi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ so that $ \mathbf{1}_{[-1,1]} \leq \psi \leq \mathbf{1}_{[-2,2]} $ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then let

$$ \phi(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!} \frac{x^m}{m!} \psi(a_n x), $$

where $(a_m)_{m\geq 0}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers chosen such that $a_m \geq 1$ for all $m$ and

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!}(2/a_m)^m < \infty. $$

Writing $\|f\| = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$ for the supremum norm on $\mathbb{R}$, for each $ k \geq 0$, we get

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!} \left\| D^k\left(\frac{x^m}{m!} \psi(a_n x)\right) \right\| \\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!} \left\| \sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{k}{j} \frac{x^{m-j}}{(m-j)!} a_m^{k-j}\psi^{(k-j)}(a_m x) \right\| \\
&\leq \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{k}{j} (2/a_m)^{m-j} a_m^{k-j} \bigl\| \psi^{(k-j)} \bigr\| \\
&\leq \Biggl[ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!} 2^{m+k} a_m^{k-m} \Biggr] \max_{0\leq i\leq k} \bigl\| \psi^{(i)} \bigr\| \\
& < \infty.
\end{align*}

So, $\phi$ is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ and term-wise differentiation is applicable indefinitely. However,

$$ D^k\phi(0) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} e^{(m!)!} \left. D^k\left(\frac{x^m}{m!} \psi(a_n x)\right) \right|_{x=0} = e^{(k!)!}, $$

and so, the sum in question diverges.