# Does the series $\sum \exp\{-(m!)!\}D^m\phi(0)$ converge for all smooth $\phi$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, divergent-series

This comes from W. Rudin's *Functional Analysis* Exercise 6.6(a). There are some questions on the same topic but none of them have this problem solved at all. For example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875885/does-the-series-sum-i-0-infty-exp-m-dm-phi0-converge-for-e) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174194/rudin-functional-analysis-chapter-6-problem-6a).

---

Here are the following questions (b) and (c). I'm not asking about these two questions here but they may help us understand what happens for (a):

> (b) Let $\Omega$ be open in $R^n$. Suppose $\Lambda_i \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega)$, and suppose that all $\Lambda_i$ have their supports in some fixed compact $K \subset \Omega$. Prove that the sequence $\{\Lambda_i\}$ cannot converge in $\mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$ unless the orders of the $\Lambda_j$ are bounded.

It is followed by (c):

> (c) Can the assumption about the supports be dropped in (b)?

So it's likely that (a) serves as a counterexample.

---

In case you are confused with the notations, I'd like to elaborate.

- $D$ of course means differentiation.
- $\mathscr{D}(\Omega)$ is the *test function* space and $\mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$ is the distribution space, i.e. the dual of $\mathscr{D}(\Omega)$.
- $\Lambda \in \mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$ if and only if, to every compact $K \subset \Omega$, there corresponds a nonnegative integer $N$ and a constant $C<\infty$ such that

$$
|\Lambda\phi| \le C \| \phi\|_N
$$

for every smooth function with support in $K$. Here

$$
\| \phi \|_N = \max \{ |D^\alpha \phi|:x \in \Omega,|\alpha| \le N \}
$$

If $\Lambda$ is such that one $N$ will do for all $K$ (but $C$ is not necessarily the same), then the smallest such $N$ is called the *order* of $\Lambda$. In particular, if $\Lambda$ has compact support, then the order is finite.

---

How should I study this argument? I think it is pretty unrealistic to construct a function explicitly. I'm thinking about the linear functional $\Gamma_n(\phi)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\exp\{-(n!)!\}D^n\phi(0)$, but how can we make use of Banach-Steinhaus theorem, for example? What about the order and support of this functional?

Another question. Should we consider smooth $\phi$ with *compact* support first, since there we are talking about distribution theory in particular?

---

Edit 1: I'm not asking about (b) and (c), I added them for the sake of context. Hope confusion is prevented.

Comment: Question in the title and body are different...As for the title, the answer is no; you can pretty much make $D^\alpha \phi(0)$ whatever you want for some $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ so just pick one that makes this series diverge.

Comment: Clarification: Are you asking about part (b) or (c)?

Comment: I think the actual question is only in the title and nowhere in the body of the question. This should be edited.

Comment: @LukasBetz I added (b) and (c) for the sake of context and nothing else. So I edited the question for this reason.

Comment: @Jose27 (b) and (c) are for context. I'm not asking for them.

Comment: @Jose27 Is it a theorem that, given one sequence $(s_n)$,  there exists a smooth function $f$ with compact support such that $D^n{f}(0)=s_n$ for all $n$? I have no idea. Would you like to give some reference if possible? Thanks!

Comment: Look for Borel's lemma.